# How change the python version 2.7.16 on my Visual Studio Code terminal to the newer python version?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, version

I recently downloaded VS Code however the python version the VS CODE terminal is 2.7.16 but the python on my mac terminal is 3.8.5. How can I change the python version to the latest on the VS code terminal?

Answer (score 0):

macOS#
The system install of Python on macOS is not supported. Instead, an installation through Homebrew is recommended. To install Python using Homebrew on macOS use brew install python3 at the Terminal prompt.

Note On macOS, make sure the location of your VS Code installation is included in your PATH environment variable. See these setup instructions for more information.

for reference:
[click here to view official vs code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute `Python: Select Interpreter`(shortcut:`Ctrl+Shift+P`) command to switch the python environment in the VSCode.

The environment of python which you are using was displayed at the bottom left of the VSCode, and you can click it directly to switch the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've solved that problem. If not, these solved the problem for me:

1. Launch VS Code.
2. Open the Command Palette (Cmd+Shift+P) and type 'shell command' to find the Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command.

For more information:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).